# Drawing by lifting pencil from paper can still beget continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

From page 105 of the 1994 edition of Spivak's Calculus:

> A continuous function is sometimes described, intuitively, as one
>   whose graph can be drawn without lifting your pencil from the paper.
>   Consideration of the continuous function    $$
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x \sin \frac 1x, & \text{if }x\neq 0 \\
> x, & \text{if }x=0
> \end{cases}
> $$   shows that this description is a little too
>   optimistic.

What does Spivak mean? $f(x)$ *can* be drawn without lifting the pen, can't it?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+sin+(1%2Fx)

(On the other hand, the function $x \mapsto x$ with domain $\mathbb R -\{0\}$ is clearly continuous but can't be drawn without lifting the pen.)

Comment: Well, it's going to be hard for anyone to draw the function in a neighborhood of zero. Certainly the function equals zero there, but can you see how the $\,x\sin1/x\,$ part looks close to zero? A mess to *accurately* draw it (in fact, impossible), though some approximation can be made

Comment: But still, the function is only *almost* an essential discontinuity at 0 -- not an actual essential discontinuity -- so shouldn't it still be possible to draw without lifting the pen?

Comment: The curve from one side of zero to the other has infinite length, I think (based on estimating the lengths of the zigzags as curve hits $1/x$ then $-1/x$ in turn). Maybe one could say that if drawn, either the pen speed becomes infinite, or it takes infinitely long to draw.

Comment: @coffeemath Ah, now Spivak's example is more acceptable--thank you. (I will accept your answer if you post it below.)

Comment: The graph oscillates infinitely many times in any neighborhood of $0$ and the oscillations become arbitrarily small in amplitude, so in order to draw it precisely you need a pen leaving a trace of width $0$. But ink traces of width $0$ are invisible, thus making the graph impossible to draw. QED. :)

Comment: @AndreaMori BTW, are all the above explanations related to the idea of essential discontinuity? If so, I still don't see how being *almost* essentially discontinuous is as good as being truly essentially discontinuous?

Comment: About the other example, the domain $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ is broken in two pieces ("not connected") thus making the graph of *any* function on it not connected.

Comment: Putting aside things like drawing speed, I think the "without lifting the pen" criterion mostly captures the fact that the graph is *connected* rather than continuous. For functions on intervals in the real line, this is the first order approximation for students to glom onto. Naturally that breaks down outside such nice circumstances, but that is why it's only an approximation.

Comment: @Ryan, the function is continuous at $\,x=0\,$...!

Comment: @rschwieb Thanks for the great insight! Your exaplanation has excellent potential to be expanded into a full answer.

Comment: Then what did you *exactly* mean by "the function is almost an essential discontinuity at zero"? The function's an **actual** continuity at this point, in fact.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The curve has infinite length between $x=-1/\pi$ and $x=1/\pi$. To see this note that it passes through each point 
$$\left(\frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi},\frac{2}{(4k+1)\pi}\right)$$ just before passing through
$$\left(\frac{2}{(4k+3)\pi},\frac{-2}{(4k+3)\pi}\right).$$
The distance between these two points is at least the absolute value of $\Delta y$, which is
$$(2/\pi)\left[\frac{1}{4k+1}+\frac{1}{4k+3}\right]$$
which as $k \to \infty$ is asymptotic to $\frac{1}{k\pi}.$ [the same asymptotic estimate occurs between the points going with $1/(4k+3)\pi$ and $1/(4k+5)\pi.$]

So by limit comparison with the sum $\sum 1/(k\pi)$, and the fact that the length computed along straight line segments is less than the curve length, we see there is indeed infinite length as claimed.

This means when drawn the pen point would have to move with unbounded speed, or else that it would take an infinitely long time to draw.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps one reason why the graph of the function cannot be drawn is that, since neither its left nor its right derivative at 0 exists, an artist starting out the graph at 0 would not be able to determine the direction in which the first stroke ought to be made.